# Need help writing a python BMI calc

Tags: python

I am new to python and and currently learning to use functions properly.

I have been tasked with making a bmi calculator using python for my homework. This bmi calculator must give the option of whether to use metric or imperial units. based on this option it will then ask for your weight and height in the respectable unit type. This is where the problem stats - no matter what i input it still uses metric units and just seems to ignore my if/elif/else statments. so this is the first problem and i cant understand where i have gone wrong here.

after that problem is solved, the bmi that it calculates needs to be put into a category and then the program should tell you which category your bmi fits into, this part doesn't even work for the metric bmi it just says:

```
    """this is the error i keep getting, the actual code for the program is below""" 
    traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:/Python33/bmi calculator 2 2 2 2.py", line 54, in <module>
        catagory(bmi)
     File "C:/Python33/bmi calculator 2 2 2 2.py", line 45, in catagory
        if bmi <18.5:
    TypeError: unorderable types: tuple() < float()


"""this is a bmi calculator that works in both imperial and metric units
and can tell your bmi category"""
bmi = ()
metric = ("metric")
Metric = ("Metric")
imperial = ("imperial")
Imperial = ("Imperial")
MetricBMI = ()
ImperialBMI = ()

answer = input (" Do you want to work out you BMI using Metric or Imperial units?")



def BMI():

    metric = ("metric")
    Metric = ("Metric")
    imperial = ("imperial")
    Imperial = ("Imperial")


    if answer.lower() == metric:      
        print("You have chose to calculate your bmi in metric units")
        Weight_kg = float(input("What is your weight in kilograms (kg)"))
        Height_m = float(input("What is your height in meters (m)?"))
        bmi = Weight_kg/Height_m/Height_m
        print("Your BMI is " + str(bmi))

    elif answer.lower() == imperial:
        print ("You have chosen to calculate your bmi in imperial units")
        Weight_lbs = float(input("What is your weight in pounds (lbs)?"))
        Height_inches = float(input("What is your height in inches??"))
        bmi = Weight_lbs*703/Height_inches/Height_inches
        print ("Your BMI is " + str(bmi))
    else:
        print ("please restart and enter either 'imperial' or 'metric'")


BMI()


def catagory(bmi):

    if bmi <18.5:
        return ("You are underweight")
    elif bmi >=18.5 and bmi <25:
        return ("You are normal weight")
    elif bmi >= 25 and bmi <30:
        return ("you are overweight")
    elif bmi >=30:
        return ("you are obese")

catagory(bmi)
```

Comment: I have completely re-written the code

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you wish to do?

```
def catagory(BMI):

    if BMI < 18.5:
        print "You are underweight"
    elif BMI >= 18.5 and BMI <25:
        print "You are normal weight"
    elif BMI >= 25 and BMI <30:
        print "you are overweight"
    elif BMI >= 30:
        print "you are obese"

def BMI():
    choice = raw_input("SI or Imperial? ")
    weight = int(raw_input("weight: "))
    height = int(raw_input("height: "))

    if choice == "SI":
        BMI = weight / (height * height)

    if choice == "Imperial":
        BMI = (weight * 703) / (height * height)
    return BMI

BMI = BMI()
catagory(BMI)
```

Your BMI function dosn't return the value that was calculated for the BMI. To change this you can either let the function return the value of BMI to the main script, as shown above with "return BMI". Or you can declare BMI a global variable in your BMI function

Answer (score 2):

Since your `BMI` function is modifying the **global** variable `bmi`, it needs to declare it:

```
def BMI():
    global bmi
    ...
```

Without the `global` declaration, Python creates a local `bmi` variable, which is forgotten when the function finishes. The error you see is the result of the attempt to use the unchanged initial value of the global `bmi` variable. You would do well to remove this initialization altogether or get rid of the global variable altogether.

Comment: As an aside, such "initialization" is useless and can only cause problems in most cases.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel In this case, I agree - initialization only increased the confusion, making the error message unrelated to the actual problem. In other cases, it may be meaningful for a global variable to have a useful initial value. Also, listing global variables near the top of the module is good practice for documentation purposes.